# In C#, how do I convert an array of bytes into a string of hex numbers?

Tags: c#, hex

In C#, what is the tidiest way to convert an array of bytes into a string of hex numbers?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa-in-c

Comment: You are right Am, missed that one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BitConverter.ToString http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.tostring.aspx

You'll get hyphens between bytes in the string, but they are easily removed.

Answer (score 2):

This should work... BitConverter is better, but this gives you more control (no hyphens) and you can get fancy with lambdas if you so wished :)

```
 public string byteToHex(byte[] byteArray) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (byte b in byteArray) {
        result.AppendString(b.ToString("X2"));
    }
    return result.ToString();
 }
```

Comment: A StringBuilder here would be much faster.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an extension I use when I need lowercase hex. e.g. Facebook requires lowercase for signing POST data.

```
    private static string ToLowerCaseHexString(this IEnumerable<byte> hash)
    {
        return hash
            .Select(b => String.Format("{0:x2}",
                                       b))
            .Aggregate((a, b) => a + b);
    }
```

Might be quicker using a StringBuilder over linq .Aggregate, but the byte arrays I pass are short.